# What mode can I choose to synchronize real-time data using `pipe` in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I find that Apache IoTDB Version 1.2.2 supports `pipe` to synchronize data. I wonder if I use this `pipe` method to synchronize real-time data, will there be any delay? Are there any different mode I can choose to better synchronize data in low latency?

Answer (score 0):

`Hybrid` mode in Apache IoTDB is real-time data transmission, which only changes to batch transmission when experiencing data accumulation to improve throughput. At other situations, `hybrid` mode is real-time transmission, which is with lower latency. On the other hand, `file` mode is for batch data transmission, with a certain delay, but higher throughput. If you are using open-source version of IoTDB, currently this only supports `file` mode.